# Vercel does not load images, videos or audios

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, vercel

I made a troll-like Vercel app. It's a 'yes or no' question. It asks "Do you wanna se my dog?". If yes, then my dog appears with a woof audio, if your answer is no, you get jumpscared. I made it out of fun, a simple code in HTML, CSS and plain JavaScript. But for some reason, when I deployed it using Vercel, it doesn't show any dog picture or jumpscare video, so it really messed up my project. How do I fix it?

GitHub repository link: https://github.com/pendragonarthur/seemydog
P.S: DevTools show this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

and

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the source of image and video, change it to:

```html
<img src="melina.png" alt="" class="hidden show" id="melina">
<video src="scare.mp4" class="myVideo" id="scare"></video>
```